# A good place to learn about image processing in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, image-processing

any websites, books etc. If someone would like to share their own experiences.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cap6411/book.pdf) is a free book which runs through some recurring tasks in computer vision and image processing.

Regarding the C++, you can take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) which is a computer vision library written in c/c++

Answer (score 2):

I've had a lot of success with open-cv. I've done an effect similar to Adobe's "Magic Wand" tool.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV

If you are interested in writing your own library you will need a pretty serious math background. The algorithms involved can be pretty intense.

Comment: OpenCV is a computer vision library, not an image processing library.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good list of simple image processing operators [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/wksheets.htm), but really the best is to take courses in DSP and image processing.

Comment: well they usually use MATLAB.

Comment: Image processing is not language-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Did some C image processing when I was in school.

I read this ebook.  It was helpful.

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/cips2ed.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) is a good API for image processing in C++, and has a [tutorial](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/tutorial/Magick++_tutorial.pdf)(PDF).